# Prove that the set $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{P}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:

> Consider the vector space $\mathbf{P}_3$ of all polynomials of degree at most 3 with real coefficients.
>
> 1. Prove that the set $H$ of all polynomials $p$ in $\mathbf{P}_3$ which vanish at $t = 2$ (meaning $p(2) = 0$) is a subspace of $\mathbf{P}_3$ (using the definition of a subspace).
> 2. Find three polynomials $\,f, g, h$ so that $H$ from the previous problem equals $\text{span}\{\,f, g, h\}$.

I know that I need to prove $H$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and it contains the zero vector. I need someone to help me get started and help explain how "which vanish at $t = 2$ (meaning $p(2) = 0$)" affects the problem.

Comment: That is simply a condition to create the subset $H$. Now just check the conditions as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific value $t=2$ does not affect the problem, but restricts the polynomials to a subspace.

To start, assume that $f,g\in H$. Show that $\lambda\,f\in H$ and $f+g\in H$, using the definition of $H$.

For the second part, take $\big((t-2),\ (t-2)t,\ (t-2)t^2\big)$.